# Does TFS VSO supports the use command line for Windows Server 2003?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, version-control, windows-server-2003, tfs-power-tools

I tried looking it all over the internet but I did not find the answer. can anyone tell me. I was wondering if we can use the command line for the TFS in windows server 2003.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. To use the `tf.exe` command. You just need VS installed, according below info:

> To launch the Visual Studio command prompt, from Windows Start, choose
>   Microsoft Visual Studio 2012, Visual Studio Tools, and then choose one
>   of the Command Prompt shortcuts.
>   Source Link: [Use Team Foundation version control commands](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/use-team-foundation-version-control-commands)

Both VS2013 and VS2015 are supported on Windows Server 2003 (with some additional requirements )
 More detail info please refer below links from MSFT:

- [Visual Studio 2013 Compatibility](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-2013-compatibility-vs.aspx)
- [Visual Studio 2015 Compatibility](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-2015-compatibility-vs.aspx)